# How do I access Google Sheets using Google Drive on Android?

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I am using the Drive API from the com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11 library, and have no problems authenticating and using the Drive file picker activity to retrieve the com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId that corresponds to one of the Sheets in the authenticated user's Drive. However, I have not been able to find any file access or parsing API that uses a DriveId to identify the file. My needs are read-only, but I'm beginning to suspect that I can't use the new Drive API to access and parse Sheets at all. Which would be a pity, as both the transparent syncing and convenience activities are very nice. Hoping someone has found the magic or can point me at a workaround.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  It's hard to find examples which would use the Google Drive API for this.